# Consumir API com react

Tags: javascript, api, react

alguem pode me ajudar como posso consulmir esta API

````
## Cadastro
```sh
$ curl --request POST \
 --url https://dev.people.com.ai/mobile/api/v2/register \
 --header 'content-type: application/json' \
 --data '{
"email":"lennon@email.com",
"name":"Lennon Coelho",
"password":"Senha@12346"
}'

## Login
```sh
$ curl --request POST \
 --url https://dev.people.com.ai/mobile/api/v2/login \
 --header 'content-type: application/json' \
 --data '{
"email":"lennon@email.com",
"password":"Senha@12346"
}'
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar o método fetch, inserindo o endereço da API, identificar o método (`POST`, `PUT`,`GET`, `DELETE`), inserir o cabeçalho necessário e mandar os dados no corpo da requisição.

**Cadastro**

```
fetch('https://dev.people.com.ai/mobile/api/v2/register/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'lennon@email.com',
    name: 'Lennon Coelho',
    password: 'Senha@12346',
  })
}).then((response) => {
    return response;
});
```

**Login**

```
fetch('https://dev.people.com.ai/mobile/api/v2/login/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'lennon@email.com',
    password: 'Senha@12346',
  })
}).then((response) => {
    return response;
});
```

Se essa é sua primeira vez usando fetch, em alguns casos será necessário instala-lo e importa-lo, segue o [link](https://github.com/github/fetch).

Além disso você pode instalar alguma extensão como [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ou [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) que facilitam a chamada de métodos REST.

Comment: Cara mais deixa eu te perguntar se pode me ajudar poderia me dar um exemplo passando tipo o name da API para um componentes só como passar

Comment: é só você inserir o nome numa variavel e colocar this.variavel ao invés do link da API